# Where and what are the "unusual crystal formations" on Alderaan?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

[The Patch 1.2 notes](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.2.0/legacy) say:

> - Several unusual crystal formations have been reported in the mountainous regions of Alderaan.

Where exactly are these crystals and what are they (what are they used for)?  My character is an artificer so I'm hoping it's something good, but I don't want to scour Alderaan if not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kappei's right, Alderaan now has an Unusual Crystal Formations that
each yield a Rough Magenta Crystal Shard.  These formations do not show up as
resource nodes on the map.

[image]
[image]

To get a Pristine Adegan Crystal from one of these Rough Magenta
Crystal Shards, use the Ancient Crystal Tuning Device at (-136, +892,
+88) in The Forge on Tython (this is near the matrix shard datacron).
For Imperials, there's a tuner on Korriban at the far west end of the
Lower Wilds behind a wall: (+176, +4, -182) (thanks cwsample).  See
[How do I get a Magenta Lightsaber Crystal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46369/6066) for how to use these
Pristine crystals!

There are three separate nodes with two or three spawn locations each.  The spawn time is two hours (separate for each node, like all resource nodes) and each node rotates through the spawn locations linearly; it's not random.

---

**Node 1**, cliffside on the South Fornak River in Kaamos Territory:

- (+1350, -1300, +310)
- (+1312, -1315, +262)

You need to jump down the hillside to get to it; if you start off at
the wrong spot use `/stuck` to reset to the top of the hill rather
than needing to go around and up it again.

This first screenshot is at the first set of coordinates, with the
second set circled:

[image: ss1]

Map view:

[image: ss2]

---

**Node 2**, hills near the Organa Medical Camp in The Juran Mountains:

- (+1187, -443, +273)
- (+1299, -564, +264)

First spot:

[image: ss3]
[image: ss4]

Second spot:

[image: ss5]
[image: ss6]

---

**Node 3**, rocks beside the steps into the Thul Palace Courtyard in The Juran Mountains:

- (+1087, -1029, +259)
- (+1076, -1033, +267)
- (+1093, -1034, +265)

Here you can see me at one spawn point with the other two circled:

[image: ss7]
[image: ss8]

Comment: Location for the Korriban crystal tuning is X: 176 Y:4 Z:-182

Comment: I have looked all over and not found these.

Comment: @Allen "All over" being at these coordinates?  They do have a two-hour spawn timer and may be hotly contested on some servers since they're pretty valuable.

Answer (score 2):

From the same patch notes:

- Magenta Crystal Shards are now found on one planet in the game. They can be refined into Pristine Magenta Crystals used in the creation of mid-level magenta color crystals through obscure means.

May it be this one?

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track.  It was a decent amount of effort to find the other info and the crystal so I've posted a separate answer, but +1!